# Why $\ln (1/x) \in L^p ( (0, 1] )$ for $1\leq p < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Why $\ln (1/x) \in L^p ( (0, 1] )$ for $1\leq p < \infty$?

From case of $p=1$ it's easy but case of $1<p$

I tried to use
the change of variable  $log(x)=e^u$ and convert
$$
\int_0^1 |\log (1/x)|^p \, dx
$$
into
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 |u|^p ue^u \, du.
$$

but i cant continue the excercise

Comment: Hint: do you know the Gamma function?

Comment: Hint: $u=-t$, and $t^{p+1} \le e^{t/2}$ for sufficiently large $t>0$.

Comment: if $u=-t$ then $\int_{-\infty}^0 |u|^p ue^u \, du$  is equal to $
-\int_{-1}^{\infty} |t|^p te^{-t} \, dt. =-(\int_{-1}^0 |t|^p te^{-t} \, dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{p+1} e^{-t} \, dt)$

Comment: Note that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a constant $C$ such that $\log(1/x) \le C x^\epsilon$ for $0<x\le 1$.  (Basically what @RobertIsrael said, but more direct.)  You can do the Gamma function stuff, but in general for these kinds of problems, it is usually easier to create crude upper bounds.